# NSInternalInconsistencyException: The specified modal presentation style doesn't have a corresponding presentation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

After updating to the iOS 8.0 SDK, I am now getting an error when attempting to present a `UIImagePickerController` from within a `UITableViewCell`:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[PartsSearchViewController 
_presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:], 
/SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.0.1/UIViewController.m:5726

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'The specified modal presentation style doesn't 
have a corresponding presentation controller.'
```

My `UITableViewCell` "PartCell" is declared like this:

```
@interface PartCell : UITableViewCell <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

It's failing on the PartCell's `presentViewController` line below:

```
- (IBAction)takeAuditImageClicked:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = (id)self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationNone;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // FAILING ON THE LINE BELOW:
    [[UIViewController topMostController] presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];  
}
```

Here is the code from the `UIViewController` "PartSearchViewController" that generates the cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"partCell";
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PartCell" bundle:nil];
    [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    PartCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];// forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[PartCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    [self fetchedResultsController:[self fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:tableView] configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

After looking through `UIViewController` and `UIImagePickerController` docs, I can't figure out what has changed about it for the code to now fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with

```
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationNone;
```

Commenting the line or changing the presentation style option to any other value did not throw the error.

I'm guessing that pre-8.0 SDK simply ignored this setting and defaulted to UIModalPresentationFullScreen - but this is definitely a guess. If anyone has a better answer, I will mark it accordingly!

From Apple docs:

> **UIModalPresentationNone**
>
> A nonmodal view presentation or dismissal.
>
> Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

(Of the seven presentation style options available for `modalPresentationStyle`, `UIModalPresentationNone` was the only one that threw the above error.)

Comment: My issue is playerController.modalPresentationStyle = .none